# Exception weblogic.deployment.QueryProxyImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.TypedQuery when I build a Criteria-Based TypedQuery

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x, criteria-api

Good day!

I'm using a Criteria Query to build a query to a table, with some predicates, like this:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery q = cb.createQuery();
        Root<Foo> root = q.from(Foo.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        [added some predicates]

        q.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

As you can see, there is nothing strange in this code snippet...but when I build the typed query to get the result list of the query:

```
TypedQuery<Foo> finalQuery = em.createQuery(q);
List<Foo> result =  finalQuery.getResultList();
```

I get an exception when I run in Weblogic 10.3.5, in the typed query creation line:

```
weblogic.deployment.QueryProxyImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.TypedQuery
```

I build this entire code snippet based on a Oracle Example, which you can find in this URL: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html

What do you think could be the error?

Thanks to everyone!

EDIT: This exception is showed when you haven't put the JPA 2 library in the weblogic classpath. You have to add the next line in your commEnv.sh/commEnv.cmd file:

**Linux**:

PRE_CLASSPATH=${BEA_HOME}/modules/javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar:${BEA_HOME}/

modules/com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar

export PRE_CLASSPATH

**Windows**:

set PRE_CLASSPATH=%BEA_HOME%\modules\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-

0.jar;%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar

Answer (score 1):

try writing:

```
CriteriaQuery<Foo> q = cb.createQuery();
```

before you had:

```
CriteriaQuery q = cb.createQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but while creating a `namedquery` instead of `createQuery`. Previously it was working fine. But when `TransactionAttribute`, `TransactionAttributeType.Not_SUPPORTED`, it is throwing `weblogic.deployment.QueryImpl` `cannot be cast to` `TypedQuery`. When I removed the transaction attribute, it worked!

Comment: Upvoted because I had the same issue, and this solution worked for me. I changed `TransacitonAttributeType.SUPPORTS` to `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED` and it worked.